# Where to find the date code or lot trace code on a Texas Instruments LMZ14202?

Tags: integrated-circuit, texas-instruments

I have a Texas Instruments LMZ14202. I'm trying to find the date code or lot trace code for this chip.

The top of the chip shows the part number (obviously) and an **8-digit** alphanumeric string of characters above the part number. Texas Instruments' website says that their lot trace codes are **7 digits**.

*If the 8-digit number isn't the lot trace code, what is it?*

I've uploaded a photograph of the chip with the number I *think* is the lot trace code circled in red.

[image: Texas Instruments part with lot trace circled]

Comment: That looks like an old National Semiconductor part from before the acquisition by TI in (I think 2010).  So the date/lot code scheme has probably changed since that part was made.  I'm guessing that by the old National logo on the part.

Comment: It's possible that's a clone and not made by TI / NS.